# rails clean all relation dependencies of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, relationship

I have a model like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :notifications, dependent: :delete_all
   has_many :foo, dependent: :delete_all
   has_many :bar, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

How can I start `dependent: :delete_all` like I call `my_user.destroy` but without destroy or delete my user ?

If I just want reset all links without lost my user?

I need generic process, not do manually :

```
my_user.notifications.delete_all
my_user.foo.delete_all
my_user.bar.delete_all
```

why? because if later, my app evolved with a new "baz" has_many relation, it mean I should think about add `my_user.baz.delete_all`, and I will not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add this to your User model:

```
def destroy_has_many_associations
  has_many_associations = self.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)

  has_many_associations.each do |association|
    send(association.name).destroy_all
  end
end
```

When you need to reset the user, you can call `user.destroy_has_many_associations`.

You could make this method more generic by making some changes. This would allow you to destroy all associations or specific ones like has_many or belongs_to:

```
def destroy_associations(type: nil)
  reflections = self.reflect_on_all_associations(type)

  reflections.each do |reflection|
    association = send(reflection.name)
    reflection.macro == :has_many ? association.destroy_all : association.destroy
  end
end
```

If you call `user.destroy_associations`, all associations will be deleted. If you call `user.destroy_associations(type: :has_many)`, only has_many associations will be destroyed.